# Использование библиотек JS для визуализации в Java

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, визуализация

Существует большое количество отличных JavaScript библиотек по визуализации данных. Например библиотека [D3js](http://d3js.org/). 
Так же существует приложение на JavaFX. К нему нужно прикрутить визуализацию как элемент Scene.
Можно ли (и если да, то как) подключить библиотеки JS к приложению, реализация которого ведётся на Java?

---

Приведу воображаемый пример:

Есть [готовая реализация](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550#index.html) на JS которую можно использовать как визуализацию вложенности хостов в сети (количество хостов в подсети, количество подсетей в сети и т.д.).

Есть десктопный (это принципиально) клиент на JFX с инструментами для анализа этой сети, в котором можно посмотреть её визуализацию. Но реализация самой визуализации написана на другом языке. Можно ли как нибудь её перенести в Java? В идеале что бы элементы (кружки/кривые и т.д.) оставались доступными для изменений, но, если уж никак, то сойдёт и просто сгенерировать на основе JS изображение и уже его передать в клиент, или предложите ещё варианты решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java имеет WebView - встроенный браузер, основанный на Webkit и умеющий многое из HTML5. Поэтому нет никакой проблемы показать HTML-содержимое (включая CSS и JS) в вашем приложении. Вот [подробная статья от Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) с примерами (англ.)

Поэтому вы можете создать заготовку HTML+CSS+JS, передать туда данные о конкретной топологии и показать в WebView отработавший скрипт со схемой.